# Erro ao usar uma função fora do script em Python

Tags: python, funções, script

Criei uma função que utiliza outras funções que não estão no mesmo script, ao executar o programa encontro um erro, afirmando que a função fora do script não está definida. Obrigatoriamente, todas as funções a serem utilizadas precisam estar no mesmo script?
[image: Script principal função circle e as funções fora do script distance e area.]

Comment: Eu não entendi muito bem, mas as outras funções estão em outro arquivo, certo? Se for isso, use `import nome_do_arquivo`, e use `nome_do_arquivo.distance(parametros)` para chamar a função.

Comment: Ao invés de imagem o ideal seri q vc colocasse o codigo, além disso a pergunta esta demasiadamente obscura. Em que arquivo vc chama "outras funcoes"? quantos arquivos são? consegue colocar um exemplo com duas funcoes minimas (helo world, por exemplo) uma chamando a outra?

Answer (score 0):

Não. Você pode simplesmente deixar os 2 scripts no mesmo diretório, e no que você for executar, escreve na primeira linha "import NomeDoOutroScript" (sem as aspas). Para cada outro script que tenha funções que você queria usar, você deve fazer um import. Ou pode fazer "import script1,script2,script3,...,scriptN" (sem aspas).
Exemplo:

```
import ScriptQueContemDistance, ScriptQueContemArea

#seu código aqui
```